# Как сделать Рабочий SharedPreference для TextView c значениями intenger?

Tags: java, android

Вот мои попытки. Кто умеет это делать скажите в чём ошибка?
                   Main
https://github.com/Nordis1/SharedPref/blob/master/MainActivity.java
                   xml
https://github.com/Nordis1/SharedPref/blob/master/Activity_main.xml

```
sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPref.edit();
        editor.putInt("SAVED",0);
        editor.putInt("SAVED_B",0);
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Text is Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                      /* А если так то*/
                                       /*try_2 Во втором случае  выдаёт туже ошибку FATAL EXCEPTION только при запуске onSave */

/*sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPref.edit();
        editor.putInt("SAVED", Integer.parseInt(team_a_score.getText().toString()));
        editor.putInt("SAVED_B",Integer.parseInt(team_a_score_B.getText().toString()));
        editor.apply();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Text is Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/


    }
    public void onLoad(View view){
        sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);
        int teamA = sPref.getInt("SAVED",0);
        int teamB = sPref.getInt("SAVED_B",0);
        team_a_score.setText(teamA);
        team_a_score_B.setText(teamB);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Text is Loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException` возникающая при попытке найти строковый ресурс. ПОпытка происходит когда вызывается перегруженный метод `setText(@StringRes int text)`.

Чтобы вызывался нужная вам версия метода, а именно `setText(@Nullable String text)` надо передавать туда строку, не число. Т.е. вот так:

```
textView.setText(String.valueof(intVariable));
```